# How to configure puppet class without redeclaring class?

Tags: python, puppet

I am trying to use the puppet module here:  https://forge.puppet.com/Siebjee/python

However when I use the following code:

```
 # install pyenv
  class { 'python::config':
      bashrc => '/home/user/.bashrc',
  }
  class { 'python':
    versions      => ['3.8.2'],
    pyenv_version => 'v1.2.18',
    user          => 'user',
    group         => 'user',
  }
```

I get an error:

```
Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Class[Python::Config] is already declared at (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/ld_packages/manifests/init.pp, line: 67); cannot redeclare
```

This is because the class `python::config` is already instantiated in the main python class.

How can I configure the module using `python::config` without re-declaring the class and causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

For most purposes, you should use include-like class declarations, not resource-like ones, and customize class parameters via Hiera.  Among the advantages of doing so is reducing the cross-section for duplicate class declaration issues.

But there are also module-design issues around this topic, and it seems like the module you are using is poorly designed in this respect.  It documents its class `python::config` as a public one, yet its main class declares `python::config` via a resource-like declaration.  Generally speaking, resource-like class declarations are inappropriate for public classes of any module.  They make sense primarily for one module class to declare a private class of the same module, making avoiding duplicate declarations an issue internal to the module.

As for what to do, since class `python` already unconditionally declares class `python::config`, you do not need to redeclare it at all, but if you do, then you should use an `include` statement, and you should put that *after* the declaration of class `python`.  If it is actually possible to customize the parameters of `python::config`, then you would need to do so by adding an appropriate entry in your Hiera data:

```
python::config::bashrc: '/home/user/.bashrc'
```

Alternatively, if I am reading the module's docs correctly then you can achieve the same effect by instead customizing the Hiera data for key `python::user`:

```
python::user: user
```